# How to Force Delete Folder in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I get the notice `There was a problem completing this request.` often. My Dropbox size is 1 TB. With much data, those errors/warnings are daily. 
The error comes in the online GUI/Web interface. Removing such a file locally, does not remove the file. I think the problem is Dropbox's internal problem. 
I think there can be a solution.

---

How can you Force Delete Folder in Dropbox?

Comment: If it's Dropbox's internal problem, wouldn't you have more luck contacting the people who have access to Dropbox's internals (i.e. their tech support team)?

Comment: @grawity Their customer service is bad. It is non-responsive. I am using Pro-account with all extra features. They just answer Business account customers. Feel free to contact them if you have such an account.

Comment: What are you trying to delete? How many folders and how many files are in the folder? Is it a lot of little files, or just a few big files? Have you tried to delete in smaller sets? Why does deleting locally not remove the file? Does it keep syncing down, or something else holding the file? Does the file have a virus/malware? Did you turn of anti-virus/malware? Have you tried deleting the folder/file in Windows Safe Mode? Have you tried a program such as LockHunter to erase the folder/files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While deleting the file locally should absolutely remove it from Dropbox, you could try removing it from the web interface. Simply select the file in the web interface and use the delete button that appears in the row of icons. (Note it is *not* the trash can that is always visible, which shows deleted files.)

[image: Dropbox File Action Icons]

If this does not work, there is definitely something wrong and you should contact Dropbox for assistance.

Comment: I did exactly this: *Online GUI*.

Comment: Is there a distinction between your "web interface" and the OP's "online GUI"?

Comment: No. There is no distinction between those two things.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had only tried deleting the file locally (from one of the synced computers). If you've tried what I wrote, then it's definitely time to contact them. There is no more direct way to delete a file than what you've tried. (Okay, you could download the API and try to write your own app to delete it, but that's absurd and probably will fail in exactly the same way.)

Comment: They do not answer cusmoters' questions and feedback. I am moving away from Dropbox because of their bad customer service. I have paid them 200 euros now 3 years. I love to stop this because I cannot get work done with their service. I am moving to `ownCloud`.